# Using the clint progress bar to show the status of urllib.urlretrieve()

Tags: python, iterator, urllib, clint

The [clint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/clint/) progress bar is based on an iterator.
urllib.urlretrieve() has a callback that reports the completion of a chunk downloading.
Can I set the iterator to be in a certain position everytime the callback is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint/blob/develop/clint/textui/progress.py), i see that it only goes up. To start at a specific value, use:

```
for i in progress.dots(range(your_start_value)): pass
```

To backspace, try:

```
sys.stderr.write(' \b\b' * amount); sys.stderr.flush()
```

That probably won't work without using the `colorama` module's locate feature, in which case you'd be better off simply writing ("=" * percent_done + " " * percent_left).